# Exchange expired EU driving licence for a UK license

Tags: driving-license

I'm Italian and I've been living in the UK since January. My Italian licence expired in 2004, because I had to exchange it for a Brasilian driving licence, as I lived in Brazil until January.

Can I exchange my Italian licence for a British licence?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a faster way of renewing my Italian driver's license as a UK expat?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/493/is-there-a-faster-way-of-renewing-my-italian-drivers-license-as-a-uk-expat)

Comment: Your Italian licence would have to be valid to [exchange for UK licence](https://www.gov.uk/exchange-foreign-driving-licence). Unless UK and Brasil have an exchange agreement, you would have to do both the theory and practical tests..